# На выводе nearest выдает ошибку

Tags: android, java, textview

Есть код. На выводе nearest выдает ошибку. Как справить?

```
GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
        Arrays.asList(locations));

public void onClick(View view){
    TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.station_name);
    helloTextView.setText(nearest);
}
```

**UPD**

Ошибка:

> cannot resolve method
> 'setText(com.example.app.GeoPoint)

Если сделать в коде

```
helloTextView.setText((CharSequence) nearest);
```

, то ошибка пропадает, но приложение вылетает. Помогите.

Comment: все взависимости от того, какую ошибку выдает.

Comment: >Рейтинг вопросов существует для того, что бы определить полезность вопроса

Эмм..с чего вы взяли? рейтинг всего лишь показывает отношение сообщества (а точнее, его части), к вопросу. Полезность он ни коим образом не отражает. Полезность - штука вообще очень субъективная. Например, вопрос может быть очень умным и глубоким, собрать 100500 плюсов, но быть при этом почти бесполезным, потому что это вопрос  по какому-нибудь Brainfuck, которым мало кто пользуется

Comment: У меня немного другой подход: я минусую откровенно тупые вопросы или вопросы рекламного характера. Плюсую, да интересные. Но если вижу нормальный вопрос, который минусуется - то исправляю плюсом (как в данном случае). Данный вопрос, конечно же не звездный, слегка туповат, но потянет на "0"

Comment: @DenShDen, @Barmaley, почитайте [справку][1], там четко описано, что такое рейтинг вопросов. Этот вопрос совершенно не тянет на 0. А вы все вредители, которые стремятся ввести пользователей этого форума в заблуждение по поводу полезности вопросов. Фу такими быть.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классе GeoPoint переопределите метод toString() так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return lat + " ; " + lon;
}
```

Потом

```
helloTextView.setText(nearest.toString());
```

Если я вас правильно понял.